# Retrieve owned auto-renew subscription item

Tags: android, in-app-purchase, in-app-billing, android-inapp-purchase

Here are how my app handles auto-renew subscription

1. Launch billing flow with BillingClient 1.1 library (BillingClient.launchBillingFlow())
2. Send purchased detail to backend to handle premium things
3. Update premium status

If I failed at step 2 (connection error, server dead...), user exited app then open again, how to retrieve owned auto-renew subscription item to notify user that they already bought an item and to do step 2 again?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Answers my own question after 5 days without any answers.
To retrieve own auto-renew items, call BillingClient.queryPurchases(BillingClient.SkuType.SUBS) after onBillingClientSetupFinished() then check if is Purchase.isAutoRenewing() = true. Don't use queryPurchaseHistoryAsync() because Purchases return from this method don't have auto-renewing state (always return false).
This answer is valid for BillingClient v1.1.